How do I know which users have edit access for Closed Won Opportunities
Sharing Settings, Permission Sets and Validation Rules? Is there a query I can run to research this?

Does this answer your question? Query on UserRecordAccess shows all permission on apex class even when the user does not have author apex permission

Replace RecordId with the opportunity's id. I don't remember right now if you can query multiple records at once, but even if you don't, you could query each opportunity individually with this.

We have hundreds of Opportunities so querying individual Opportunity would not be possible.

this is likely controlled a combination of apex triggers, validation rules, lightning page component visibility, recordtypes+pageLayouts, before save flows, and even visualforce edit button overrides
